# Running Script in Other Spreadsheet from Current Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two different Spreadsheets with their own script projects. I have created a library from SpreadsheetA and linked the same to SpreadsheetB. Now when I call the function of SpreadsheetA from the script of SpreadsheetB it runs the same in the current active sheet of SpreadsheetB while I want to run the function on selected sheet of SpreadsheetA.

```
function createDO() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); //SpreadsheetB
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getRowIndex();
  var spreadSheetAURL = "URL"; //SpreadsheetA
  var spreadSheetsInA = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadSheetAURL).getSheetByName("name");
  spreadSheetsInA.activate()
  Sheetname.Project(); //script in SpreadsheetA
};
```

I need to run the `Sheetname.Protect()` function for SpreadsheetA from the current SpreadsheetB.

Comment: Libraries don't work like that, but you could do this with a doGet(), deploying the bound script of SpreadsheetA as a web app and calling it with UrlFetch?

Comment: @Harsh - [to keep the comment] why don't you make the functions in the library generic (libraries are not meant to work like microservices - they are utility scripts and therefore follow their own set of rules), get the Spreadsheet B in the context of the A and call it a day? Something like MyLib.project(spreadsheet) that takes a spreadsheet as an arg

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to share (at least the relevant code) of this library if you want to follow this path. But I agree with @OlegValter.

Answer (score 2):

#### Possible Solution:

Firstly, it is worth noting that libraries do not work like this. As [Oleg Valter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11407695/oleg-valter) has stated, libraries are by nature utility scripts which are not bound to any one specific script/class/project.

As a workaround, however, you can set up a web app which can be called from one project to another, running code inside a `doGet()` function on the respective Spreadsheet.

A structure would look something like this:

**In Spreadsheet A:**

```js
function doGet(e) {
  var sheetName = e.parameter.sheetName
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  sheet.activate();

  // I am not how this works, but I have extrapolated from your question
  Sheetname.Project(); 
}
```

Then deploy this as a Web App from the `Publish > Deploy as web app...` menu item. The settings should be `Execute the app as: me` and `Who has access to the app: Anyone (even anonymous)`.

Then, getting the Web App URL from the dialog, in **Spreadsheet B:**

```js
function createDO() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); //SpreadsheetB
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getRowIndex();
  var webAppUrl = "URL"; //SpreadsheetA
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(webAppUrl + "?sheetName=name");
};
```

The `?sheetName=name` parameter is a URL query string which would be passed to the web app's `doGet(e)`'s event object. This is what is accessed with `e.parameter.sheetName`.

The string on the right-hand-side of the `=` in the query string needs to be the sheet name you were trying to activate originally.

#### References:

- [Web Apps | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Query string - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#:%7E:text=A%20query%20string%20is%20a,part%20of%20an%20HTML%20form.)
- [Simple Triggers - doGet(e) and doPost(e) | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#dogete_and_doposte)
- [Event Objects | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: That's basically a microservice :) One small note - I think (I am just assuming for the OP here, though) that the `Sheetname` part will probably be not needed in the web app scenario setup as I believe the `Sheetname` is the library alias and not a reference to an instance of a class ( probably, but I may be wrong )

Comment: @OlegValter Yeah, it should be noted that this isn't how libraries are meant to be used, but I figured a workaround solution is still a solution if OP doesn't want to restructure how they've written the lib. I think `Sheetname` is a library alias too, though I wondered if (read: made an educated guess) it does something with whatever the active sheet is (hence it being called directly after `spreadSheetsInA.activate()` in the original question expecting it to do something to the newly 'active' sheet in Spreadsheet A.

Comment: Very informative Rafa :) I think that should be the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rafa trying to get it done this way lets see if succeed. 'Sheetname' is the name of my project  while Project is name of the function in the .gs file

Comment: @Harsh - a bit off-topic, but this will serve you well - please do not name methods (that are not constructors) in sentence case. By convention, such names are used to easily identify references to modules and classes (and interfaces in TypeScript) and are a bit hard to parse when the name sends the wrong signal. Re: name of the project - wait, isn't it a reference to the library alias in the project you added the library to?